# Emacs org-mode display time range visually in agenda

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm looking for a way to get the agenda view in org-mode to 'block out' periods of time for entries with a specified time range. By default it lists items with a specified time range at their start time. This can make it difficult to spot overlapping items and to find areas of free time. I've googled around a fair amount, but have yet to find anything.

A [google calendar style display](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/1fLFHiN0styGRBRNyOok0ySL0EbBIyCnXxZcfCW6UGL1Lmx6noMFn0ak7pvfGVKigDYUfyWHDcs=s640-h400-e365%20%22Google%20calendar%20style%20display) for the current day in the agenda would be one possible solution, although I'm sure there are other approaches that would also work just as well.

While a pre-made solution would be ideal, I'm not opposed to implementing it myself; my elisp is still pretty rudimentary though, so pointers on how to approach it would also be much appreciated.

Comment: +1: Being able to see the blocks of time in my schedule is literally the only reason I can stand to keep using Apple Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

emacs-calfw has google calendar like view.

[kiwanami/emacs-calfw](https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw/)

### Install

`M-x package-install calfw`

then write configuration to init.el

`(require 'calfw-org)`

### Usage

Display calendar by `M-x cfw:open-org-calendar`

Filter tasks by this configuration.

`(setq cfw:org-agenda-schedule-args '(:scheduled :sexp :closed :deadline :todo :timestamp))`

other documents are [here(README.md)](https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw/blob/master/readme.md)

Comment: I'm familiar with califw, but while it is able to replicate Google Calendar's monthly view, it does not have a feature similar to Google Calendar's daily or weekly view that visually shows what time events are/their duration.

Comment: It does. Type "W" for week view and "D" for day view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the variable name is, but if you go to **Options -> Customize Emacs -> Top-Level Customization Group** and then search **org-agenda-time-grid** there is a setting called **Skip grid times already present in an entry**.

Tick the little box next to that, and you're somewhat there. At least you'll no longer see times looking like they're empty when they're not. Unfortunately it doesn't provide a strong visual representation of the time chunk itself.

EDIT: Actually, it seems this doesn't work to solve the issue. It only appeared to do so on my agenda for some reason before, but now no longer doe.

I would honestly consider this a bug as it completely violates user expectations and serves no other function than to confuse.

Answer (score 0):

[org-timeline](https://github.com/Fuco1/org-timeline) would be one way of doing it.

[image: visual timeline in org-timeline]

For the given day in the agenda, it will give you an idea of where you have items overlapping, and any gaps.